# How to access functions that use self outside of class

Tags: python, class

I have been trying to access a function made within a class outside of said class.
If self is not one of the function's parameters it works just fine, as in:

```
class Dog():   

    def Bark():
        print("woof")

Marley = Dog

Marley.Bark()
```

But If I add self to Bark() as in:

```
class Dog():

    def Bark(self):
        print("woof")

    def Bark_lots(self):
        for I in range(3):       
            self.Bark()

Marley = Dog

Marley.Bark_lots()
```

Then python throws a type error:

TypeError: Bark_lots() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Everything that I've searched up just talks about why self is needed and what it does. I am clearly missing something, and from past experience it is probably simple. Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

(Also I am new to stack exchange/ stack overflow, If I broke any of the rules please alert me to where and I will fix it.)

Comment: You need to create [Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) if you want to access a method with `self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the call сlass you need to put parenthesis (`Dog()`, not `Dog`):

```
Marley = Dog()
Marley.Bark()
```

Comment: So it was simple, Thanks!

Comment: @Drickken: Glad to be of help. Choose the answer to help other users with the same problem.

Comment: Will do, Stack Overflow wants me to wait 10 min from the asking of the question

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you're missing a little part. I've noticed that you are calling a function improperly. Don't forget to type the opening and closing brackets while calling a function. The correct way would be;

```
class Dog():

def Bark(self):
    print("woof")

def Bark_lots(self):
    for I in range(3):       
        self.Bark()

Marley = Dog()

Marley.Bark_lots()
```

Comment: Don't duplicate answers, please.

Answer (score -1):

**Marley = Dog()** is different from **Marley = Dog**

**Marley = Dog** : The class itself is assigned to the variable **Marley**. **Marley** will be a reference to the class Dog.
we can use like below,

```
m=Dog
x= m()
x.bark_lots()   '''x's ref will be passed as self to the function'''
```

**Marley = Dog()** : Here you are creating an object of the class **Dog**. So when you call

```
Marley = Dog()
Marley.Bark_lots()
```

the object **Marley's** reference will be considered as self param.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.